# why @@ROWCOUNT is needed when EF generates insert SQL

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I found Immediately after the INSERT, Entity Framework Core sends another command to the database server:

```
SELECT [Id]
FROM [Responses]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
```

but why @@ROWCOUNT is needed to be checked? isn't that `scope_identity()` returning the unique key that we need to know about the newly inserted record? checking @@ROWCOUNT is pretty redundant, isn't it?

Additional Info:

if I insert two rows separately, there is only two "1 row affected" text, not "2 row affected"

[image]

Comment: `@@ROWCOUNT` <> `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. `@@ROWCOUNT` will return the number of rows affects by the last statement, where as `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. They are completely different.

Comment: What if several rows were inserted?

Comment: It appears that it's intentionally put there to ensure that if more than one row was inserted previously, the select would return nothing. Which makes sense because you only want to return the new `Id` if you're certain it's the correct one.

Comment: @Larnu  I don't get your post, I didn't ask the difference between @@ROWCOUNT and SCOPE_IDENTITY() and I know what they stand for

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  you made some points but I'm still feeling confused, what do you mean by 'certain it's the correct one', if I insert two records, that would be two "1 row affected" text, not "2 row affected", so I will always  get the latest one I inserted , isn't it?

Comment: If two records were inserted, `@@rowcount=2`, which means the `where` clause becomes false and no records are returned.

Comment: @secondimage Whether you have 2 x (1 row affected) or 1 x (2 rows affected) is dependent on your previous code, which would be helpful to see. Generally, if you insert two records with 1 query you would get 1 x (2 rows affected), and thus @@ROWCOUNT=2. The only way to get the *same* query to give 2 x (1 rows affected) would be to have the query inside a cursor.

Comment: We're basically guessing about the intentions of EF here... and it looks like it's intentional to stop an edge case where two records might somehow have been inserted. It's 'defensive coding' - without that, it's remotely possible that an incorrect `Id` could be returned which could be catastrophic. Better off throwing an exception in the code (which I guess is what it wil do if the `Id` is NULL or not returned)

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis  I have added sth to my post, could you have a look? I mean I added two rows separately

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid so you mean if my query just insert one record, then it should return the primary key,if my query insert two rows, then nothing should be returned?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking about why a certain feature is written a certain way in EF. The OP would need to ask the developers of that tool, not people on SO.

Comment: It is possible for the `INSERT` to fail. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will still return the value of the last generated identity in this case, and the kicker is, of course, that this value might match a row that already exists which was not inserted by us. (Indeed, that might be the reason the `INSERT` failed in the first place -- because someone used `identity_insert` or `dbcc checkident` explicitly.) Try `SET XACT_ABORT OFF; DECLARE @t TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1000, 1) CHECK (ID <> 1000)); INSERT @t DEFAULT VALUES; SELECT @@ROWCOUNT, SCOPE_IDENTITY();`.

Comment: True that’s the other case - @@rowcount=0

Comment: @secondimage If you run `insert Inventory(Make,Color,PetName) values ('Toyota','grey','NA'),('Ford','Red','NA')` you'll get 2 row(s) affected. In this case, @@ROWCOUNT=2 so original query is designed to return nothing.